# jQuery: Touchmove not working as expected on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touch

The app works wonderfully on desktop, but not on mobile. When you click DONE, the app will open a new window and show you the output of the drawings, but on iOS, all the coordinates are 0,0... so it looks like the points simply are not being saved in mobile devices.

The problem is most likely either at lines 109 to 111 or lines 171 to 184 of the JS which I am including below:

The section that handles the touch events:

```
 $(trackingLayer).on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    isTracking = true;
    curMouseX = curMouseY = -1;
    if (curTool === "draw") {
        var o = {};
        o.painLevel = curPainLevel;
        o.path = [];
        DrawPoints.push(o);
    }
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    trackMoveMouse($(this), e);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave touchend', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    isTracking = false;
});
```

And the area that records the points:

```
var canvasOffset = ID.offset(); //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
        curMouseX = e.pageX - canvasOffset.left;
        curMouseY = e.pageY - canvasOffset.top;

        if (curMouseX !== -1 && prevMouseX !== -1) {
            var o = {};
            o.x = curMouseX / curZoom;
            o.y = curMouseY / curZoom;
            DrawPoints[DrawPoints.length - 1].path.push(o);
            //log("Shapes Recorded: " + DrawPoints.length);
            drawImage();
        }
```

I have set up a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/nbernhard/dSED8/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!